# reverse polish notation fuction

Tags: c++11

a function `evaluateCountdown` that takes a string containing a mathematical expression written in Reverse Polish Notation, and returns the result of evaluating the expression, as a double.

In reverse polish notation (RPN), operators are written after rather than between what they act upon. For instance:

```
3.0 4.0 +
```

is the same as the usual (infix) notation (3.0 + 4.0). Or the below expression in `RPN` format:

```
3.0 4.0 + 2.0 *
```

is the same as `(3.0 + 4.0) * 2`

I am getting a logic error, the input `"3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *"` is supposed to give the output `-2.0` however the output I am receiving when calling the main function is `0`, the input string must be in the format where the numbers are doubles, the function works when the input string is, for example, `"3 4 - 2 *"` (returns a correct answer of `-2`), but not when in the form `"3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *"`

the function `evaluateCountdown` iterates through the input string and when it finds a number it pushes that number into the stack as a double, so for example when `tokens[i]` is `3` then `3 + tokens[i + 1] + tokens[i + 2]`, in this case `'3' + '.' + '0'` is pushed into the stack as a double. However, this isn't happening and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using std::vector;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::stack;
using std::iterator;
using std::endl;
using std::stod;

double evaluateCountdown(string & tokens) {
    // this method does not work if the string is empty or a string of just spaces, string must be a expression in RPN
    stack<double> stack;
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
       
        if (tokens[i] == '+')
        {
            double val1 =  stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            double val2 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            stack.push((val1 + val2));
        }

        else if (tokens[i] == '-')
        {
            double val1 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            double val2 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            stack.push((val2 - val1));
        }

        else if (tokens[i] == '*')
        {
            double val1 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            double val2 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            stack.push(val1 * val2);
        }

        else if (tokens[i] == '/')
        {
            double val1 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            double val2 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            stack.push((val2 / val1));
        }

        else if (tokens[i] == ' ')
        {
            // if char is a space do nothing and move onto the next char.
        }

        else
        {
            string str = "";
            char c1, c2, c3;
            c1 = tokens[i];
            c2 = tokens[i + 1];
            c3 = tokens[i + 2];
            // concat chars togther to get required string eg '3' + '.' + '0'
            auto ans = string(1, c1) + c2 + c3;
            str += ans;
            double val = stod(str);
            stack.push(val);
        } 

        

        
    }
    double val = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    return val;
   
}

int main() {
    string s = "3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *";
    double ans = evaluateCountdown(s);
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: The part that parses the number consumes three characters - but `i` is only incremented by one. On next iteration, `tokens[i]` is the period, and the code goes into the number-parsing again, this time with `".0 "` (period, zero, space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code finds a number, it should increment `i` by two, unless doing that the code does not work.

Therefore, the `else` condition could be written as follows(The rest of the `else` statement will remain intact):

```
c1 = tokens[i];
c2 = tokens[++i];
c3 = tokens[++i];
```

If you are a new programmer, I would recommend that when you encounter a problem like that, you use a debugger to debug your program (even the most professional programmers need to debug their code).